# 2 continuous functions with the property $f(g(x))=x$.

Tags: continuity

$f, g\colon \mathbb {R}\to \mathbb {R}$ continuous functions such that $f(g(x))=x$. Prove that $g(f(x))=x$.
Since $f$ is surjective, we basically have to prove that $f$ is injective. For $g$ is clearly, but how can I prove that $f$ is injective ? Please, help me!

Comment: This holds even when $f$ is not surjective. Hint: a continuous function is invertible if and only if it is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. You will easily be able to google a reference to this .

Comment: $f$ is surjective because $f(g(x))=x$. It was just an observation. And I know that stuff already. I saw that $g$ is a strictly monotonic function, but I haven't thought that it will help. But now that I think about it, it might help.

Comment: How about $g(x)=\tan(x)$ and $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ ? That ain't surjective, at least not in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @KurtG. $\tan(x)$ is not continuous on ${\mathbb R}$.

Comment: @Gribouillis . Right ! OP wants $g$ to be defined on the whole $\mathbb R$. Take it back.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- As $g$ is continuous and injective, it is strictly monotonic
- if $\ell := \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \in {\mathbb R}$, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(g(x)) = f(\ell)$, contradicting $f(g(x)) = x$. Hence $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \pm \infty$
- Same result with $\lim_{x\to -\infty}g(x)$
- conclude that $g$ is surjective.
- If $y=g(x)$ then $f(y)= f(g(x)) = x$, hence $g(f(y)) = g(x) = y$.